# add IMAGE function to only one column of data collected via IMPORTXML

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I import data from a single `IMPORTXML` and divide it into two columns as follows:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(1,{1;IMPORTXML(A1,"

//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='photo']/a/img/@src | 
//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='name large-link']/a/@href")},

(ROW(A:A)+1)*2-TRANSPOSE(sort(ROW($A$1:$A$2)+0,1,0)))))
```

[image]

I would like to know if there is any way of not having to use more than one call to importxml and adding the `IMAGE` function only in the first column, so I don't have to put it separately as I currently do.

link to Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10_G3QjcLcE9dYz_0m8PjPxHDAAaKL7BGEehTfmprYTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best you can do with one formula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IFERROR(IMAGE(IMPORTXML(A1,
 "//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='photo']/a/img/@src"))), 
 QUERY(IFERROR(HLOOKUP(1, {1; IMPORTXML(A1,
 "//table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='photo']/a/img/@src | //table[@class='table squad sortable']//td[@class='name large-link']/a/@href")},
 (ROW(A:A)+1)*2-TRANSPOSE(SORT(ROW($A$1:$A$2)+0, 1, 0)))), "where Col1 !=''", 0)})
```

[image: 0]